# adb no devices list не видит устройств

Tags: android-studio, cordova, adb, android-emulator

Использую cardova для создания мобильного приложения. Проблема в эмуляции приложения на телефоне. Утилита adb не видит моё устройство. В диспетчере устройств видно моё устройство оно определятся через два драйвера:
- Android Adb Interface,
- Переносные устройства MTP.

Система - windows 7 64 bit.  Установлена Android Studio 64.

в adb_usb_ini прописал ID устройства, не помогло.
Что делать, как добиться, чтобы adb видел устройство?

Comment: pdanet пробовал установить на телефон + пк?

Comment: проверьте, включена ли отладка по USB на смартфоне

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych простите, не понял вашего вопроса.

Comment: @Pollux отладка на телефона включена, deploy на телефон разрешен, самое непонятное состоит в том, что раза два в листе устройств Id телефона отображался, а потом при следующем наборе команды adb devices опять исчезал (купил новый usb шнур, думал мало ли контакт где-то лагает, не помогло).

Comment: `adb_usb.ini` уже давно не используется

Answer (score 1):

Итак переставил драйвера ещё раз, перезагрузился, подключил телефон к другому usb разъему и всё взлетело.